# How do I animate a constraint change in a parent view controller from within a container view? (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, animation

I have a container view in a view controller that contains a button that moves a label down in the parent view controller each time it is pressed. I am passing the constraint for the label through to the container via prepare for segue. From there I am able to modify the constraint, but it will not animate.

How should I be doing this?

[visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYXBG.gif)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerSegue" {
            let container = segue.destination as? Container
            container?.LabelTopConstraint = LabelTopConstraint
        }
    }
}

class Container: UIViewController {

    weak var LabelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction func MoveLabelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        LabelTopConstraint.constant += 30
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 % working answer you need to update layout of parent view like ..

```
@IBAction func MoveLabelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    self.LabelTopConstraint.constant += 30 // Your constraint constant change


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
        self.parent?.view.layoutIfNeeded() // Force lays of all subviews on parent view .
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]